# libgdx - actor interaction, what mechanism?

Tags: java, libgdx, 2d, collision-detection

I have a libgdx game where I want to move a sprite when it is touched and dragged. If it comes close to other sprites I want to highlight them and I want to automatically slide into position if the sprite is released (touch up) and the sprite is close enough to another sprite.

So if I use actors the actors have to know about the other actors.

Is there already some mechanism to handle this in libgdx? Should I use something else than actors?

I could have a "manager" class which is called by the actors but I rather it would be the other way around, the "manager" knows about all the actors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no easier mechanism in Scene2d than just iterating over actors and checking theirs position. If there are very many actors on the stage the operation can be expensive because of taking **O(n<sup>2</sup>)** (you have to check every actor with every others).

**The good news is that you have to check only one actor with other** which will make **O(n)** and is totally acceptable.

You also do not need any outer manager to check actors - just when actor is grabbed you should set it the flag and if the flag is true in the **act** actor's method you should check another actors - of course you need to create your own **MyActor** class extending **Actor**

```
class MyActor extends Actor
{
    ...

    public boolean amIBeingDragged = false;

    public void act(float delta)
    {
        super.act(delta);

        if( amIBeingDragged )
        {
            Vector2 position = new Vector2(this.getX(), this.getY());

            for(Actor actor : this.getStage().getActors())
            {
                 if(actor == this) continue;

                 if(position.dst( new Vector2( actor.getX(), actor.getY() < thresholdDistance )
                 {
                     this.setPosition( actor.getX(), actor.getY() );
                 }
            }
        }
    }
}

//drag's listener methods
public void dragStart(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer)
{ 
    ( (MyActor) event.getTarget() ).amIBeingDragged = true;
}

public void dragStop(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer)
{ 
    ( (MyActor) event.getTarget() ).amIBeingDragged = false;
}

...
```

There are of course geometric alghoritms to optimize case like this but in such simple usage I don't think it worths to deal with them.

---

If you want to try some alternative you can use [Box2D](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Box2d) (default Libgdx physics engine) collision system. The idea would be to give every actor a body and the body should have fixture bigger than actor. Then on collision you could handle the contact - **but again if you aren't using box2d already it totally does not worth to implement it just for this**.

Read more about Box2d collisions [here](http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/collision-anatomy).